# Can I use an unused bathtub as a litter box?

Tags: cats, toilet-training

I have an extra bathroom which no one in the house uses; we put our cat's litter box in it. I love cats a lot so I was thinking, if I ended up adopting a lot of them (being able to take care of them all of course) can I use the extra bathtub, if sealed really well with a bath plug, as a litter box? I'm thinking of filling it with a lot of litter so it won't need changing for at least 2 months or so.

I won't allow guests to ever see it and I will make sure to seal it really well with a bath plug. What are the positives and negatives of having a bathtub as a litter box, if cleaned daily?

Comment: You think shovel out a tub is less work than empty a litter box?

Comment: I agree with the answer - not a good idea

Comment: I don't think it's less work, but it's less shifting from place to place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Off the top of my head –

Positives:

- A bathtub is a big litter box

Negatives:

- A bathtub is a big, smelly litter box
- Very difficult to keep clean regularly as you cannot easily remove all the litter to clean the base
- Cannot move a bathtub to clean it
- Needs a lot of litter, changed regularly, which would get expensive
- Risk clogging your drain with litter etc. if not very careful
- Can likely never ever use the bathtub for a bath again, for example if you sell the house
- The cats might start using your other baths as litter boxes, if they learn that's a nice place to go
- Unpleasant surprise for any guest thinking they might want a quick shower

Comment: +1 all of these (especially *"The cats might start using your other baths as litter boxes"* -- a related ex.: one of my boxes is covered, if I place the cover on the floor while changing it, both my cats will happily go in and go on the floor). Another negative especially with lots of cats is territory issues or issues when multiple cats want to use the litter box/tub at once. The general rule of thumb is # of litter boxes = # of cats + 1, and spread throughout the house. All my instincts and experience in many households with many cats screams "you're gonna regret this". :) cc @toothless199

Comment: Lol I wasn't going to do it, just thinking it.

Comment: Also, it might be very inconvenient for an old or sick cat to enter the litter-tub.